# PostgreSQL: Can Access Crypto Function on an Admin User, But Not on a Normal User

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto

I have a PostgreSQL database with the `pgcrypto` extension installed:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;
NOTICE:  extension "pgcrypto" already exists, skipping
CREATE EXTENSION
```

I can use that extension, while logged-in to an admin user, just fine:

```
postgres=# select public.gen_salt('bf', 8);
       gen_salt            
-------------------------------
 $2_SOME_SALT_Qu
(1 row)
```

Also, the extension is available to the public schema:

```
postgres=# \dx
                  List of installed extensions
   Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description          
----------+---------+------------+------------------------------
 pgcrypto | 1.3     | public     | cryptographic functions
```

In spite of all of the above, when I try to use the crypto functions from any ordinary database user, it fails:

```
user=> select gen_salt('bf', 8);
ERROR:  function gen_salt(unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select gen_salt('bf', 8);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The same thing happens if I try to invoke `public.gen_salt` instead.

Can anyone explain how I can fix my database to allow all users to access the crypto funcitions?

Comment: Does the "ordinary database user" have access to the `public` schema, and is it in their `search_path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual prompt for psql includes the database name, not the user name.

So it looks like you logged on to a different database, not just as a different user.

You need to create the extension in each database you want to use it in.